# Define a path depending on the target platform within the Dockerfile in order to copy binaries

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I have GitHub Actions which uses `rust-cross` to perform cross-compilation for `arm64` and other hardware platforms.

I perform cross-compilation on the host machine already and wish to just use the binaries and static libraries to be copied into the `Dockerfile` and create a light Alpine Container.

### Caveat

In `rust-cross` the released binaries are under specific directories, for example:

```
arm64 -> target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/
amd64 -> target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/
armv7 -> target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/
```

### Trials

I am trying to use `case` within my `Dockerfile` which relies on `docker buildx` kit provides and provide the `TARGETPLATFORM` based on some well documented repository from [BretFisher/multi-platform-docker](https://github.com/BretFisher/multi-platform-docker-build)

```
FROM alpine as base

FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} alpine as tiny-project

# Use BuildKit to help translate architecture names
ARG TARGETPLATFORM

RUN case ${TARGETPLATFORM} in \
         "linux/amd64")  TARGET_DIR=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl  ;; \
         "linux/arm64")  TARGET_DIR=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu  ;; \
         *) exit 1 \ # ignore other architectures for now!
    esac \

WORKDIR /app

RUN cp target/<HOW TO PASS VALUE TARGET_DIR>/release/myBinary .
RUN cp target/<HOW TO PASS VALUE TARGET_DIR>/release/*.so .

FROM base as release
COPY --from=tiny-project /app/* ./

RUN echo '#!/bin/ash' > /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo 'echo " * Starting: /myBinary $*"' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo 'exec /myBinary $*' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 7447/udp
EXPOSE 7447/tcp
EXPOSE 8000/tcp

ENV RUST_LOG info

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I have tried doing a lot of variations but it seems like `TARGET_DIR` is not being recognized on the host machine

```
RUN cp ./target/$(echo $TARGET_DIR)/release/myBinary /
RUN cp ./target/$(echo $TARGET_DIR)/release/*.so /

# as well as storing the value in a file and calling it
# echo aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu > /tmp/rust_target.txt

RUN cp ./target/$(cat /tmp/rust_target.txt)/release/zenohd /
RUN cp ./target/$(cat /tmp/rust_target.txt)/release/*.so /
```

But it seems like the neither the file nor the variable are available to the host and I keep getting an error during my GitHub Actions Workflow Log

### Requirements

I wish to keep a single `Dockerfile` and based on the `platform` from `docker buildx build` command I want to copy the binaries from appropriate source directories to the destination directory in the Dockerfile.

How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Each `RUN` command runs in its own shell (and its own container), so you can't set variables in one `RUN` command that last beyond that Dockerfile line.

However, each `RUN` line also is implicitly wrapped in `sh -c`, and so you can use ordinary shell constructs to run multiple commands in a single `RUN` instruction.  Since you haven't left a single Dockerfile line, the shell variable you set will still be valid:

```sh
WORKDIR /app
# All in a single RUN line:
RUN case "${TARGETPLATFORM}" in \
         "linux/amd64")  TARGET_DIR=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl  ;; \
         "linux/arm64")  TARGET_DIR=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu  ;; \
         *) exit 1 ;; \
    esac; \
    cp target/$TARGET_DIR/release/myBinary .; \
    cp target/$TARGET_DIR/release/*.so .
```

It would also be reasonable to put this logic into a shell script that you `COPY` and `RUN`, or to create a staging directory on the host that contains the files you want to include in the layout you want and use that directory as the `docker build` context directory.

```sh
rm -rf docker-build
mkdir docker-build
TARGET_DIR=...
cp "target/$TARGET_DIR/release/myBinary" docker-build/myBinary
cp Dockerfile docker-build
docker build ./docker-build
```

Comment: Actually I suspect the call to `target/` directory will fail here too since it is unable to find the directory from the host machine. Here is a [failed log](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/zenoh/runs/2894957507) and in the raw logs there is an error `ls: target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/zenohd: No such file or directory`
The only plausible solution as you mentioned was to move the binaries into a dedicated host directory and then copy them in the container

Comment: You could `COPY target target` in the first stage to get the build tree into the image.

Comment: You are right in that aspect. I tried copying the `target` into a build stage and it works. I was able to pass my builds using the following [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/zenoh/blob/master/Dockerfile) however my alpine container refuses to find the binaries